# Gridster center align when content wrapper is 100%?

Tags: css, html, gridster

Has anyone figured out how to center align the content-wrapper in Gridster, if the wrapper is set to 100%?

I can't seem to get it to work.

When the browser window is resized there is some right-padding that I can't seem to change.

Can anyone help?

See this: http://www.danieldoktor.dk/test5/test5.html

Comment: Do you want to align the box in the center of the window, or do you want to center the text in the box?

Answer (score 1):

So the problem here is that jquery is giving the LI elements a position absolute. I have overwritten that using important, you can then align everything center by using text-align and display inline-block.

```
.contentWrapper {
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: static !important;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}

.gridster {
    margin: 0 auto;
    opacity: .8;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .6s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .6s;
    -o-transition: opacity .6s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .6s;
    transition: opacity .6s;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Hope that makes sense and helps.

Comment: And a fiddle with your work-around: http://jsfiddle.net/KYEkc/1/

But as you can se, the widgets can't be moved around, it's only the shadows in the back that moves when you drag

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it that well, I don't know?.. But can it be done, so either the class and content-holder '.demo' is centered (equal padding-space in each side) or the ul '.gridster' is center-aligned in the content-holder?